# Matlab & and < operator

Tags: matlab

In this expression

```
lmin=lminflag & ~kmod & actminsub<nsm*pminu & actminsub>pminu;
```

is the & operator like a bitwise AND operator? lminflag and kmod are both arrays with either logical 1 or 0 as elements and lmin turns out to be either 1 or 0 as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

1. `&`  is a per-element AND operator.
2. `&&` is a scalar AND operator, with conditional execution of the remainder of the statement.

For example, given:

```
a = true;
b = false;
aa = [true false];
bb = [true true];
fnA = @()rand>0.5; %An anonymous function returning true half the time
```

Then:

```
a &  b;  %returns false
a && b; %returns false (same as above)
```

However

```
aa &  bb;  %this an error    
aa && bb; %returns the array [true false]
```

It's more interesting when the operands are functions, with side effects.

```
b &  fnA;  %Returns false, and the `rand` function is called (including a small performance hit, and an update to the random state)
b && fnA;  %Returns false, and the `rand` function was not called (since `b` is false, the actual value of `fnA` doesn;t effect the result
```

Comment: +1. Small remark though: note that `rand>0.5;` is at least twice as fast as ` logical(round(rand));`